# CALayer Antialiasing not as good as UIView antialiasing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, calayer

I've been trying to animate circle drawing using CALayer. It all works well, but the problem is - drawn circle is not antialiased enough. It has a bit too rough borders, (or blurred if rasterize is used). (AntiAliasing is enabled)

Tried also:

> edgeAntialiasingMask = kCALayerLeftEdge | kCALayerRightEdge |
>   kCALayerBottomEdge | kCALayerTopEdge;

to no avail.

Here is an example how it looks like without rasterization:
[image]

And here is an example with rasterization: (tried values from 1.0 till 4.0 (just to be sure. Result - the same.))

[image]

And here is the same circle, but drawn inside UIView drawrect:

[image]

You can see, that circle drawn using UIView drawrect is looking much better.

The reason I cannot use UIView is because I need to animate circle filling. Using CALayer it is really easy, but to do the same on UIView, I don't really know if it is even possible. (I could try to launch drawrect: every 1/60 seconds, but I think it will get laggy, as it is not intended that way).

**So - does anyone have any solution how I could make drawn circles/lines on CALayer look the same as drawn on UIView?**

Comment: Note: edgeAntialiasingMask is enabled on all edges by default so your code should have had no affect. However, setting it to `= 0;` could have an affect (on the edges of an image)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've had issues with pixelated drawing in a `CALayer` on retina devices before. (I'm assuming you're seeing the issue on retina devices) Doing the following fixed the issue I was experiencing:

```
layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

You shouldn't need to deal with rasterization or antialiasing. In my own code, I had initially implemented drawing something to a `UIView` that I later changed to be drawn in a `CALayer`, and simply setting the `contentsScale` property made both draw identically.

Comment: OMG, I cannot believe that I missed this one. This works!!!! Thank You !!!! You made my day :)

Comment: Do you need to set contentsScale before drawing the circle or does it not matter? Thanks!

Comment: It's so weird that this only works for me when setting it from a view, but not if I set it in a CALayer subclass.