# Drawing anti-aliased line

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, antialiasing

I'm drawing a line on the screen which includes diagonal lines which in turn are drawing like this:

[image]

Notice how it doesn't look smooth at all. I've read a few articles on this and it would seem [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392675/calayer-antialiasing-not-as-good-as-uiview-antialiasing) looks the one closer to the issue I'm having, but the solution is not working for me.

Here's how I setup the layer:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Instantiate the navigation line view
    CGRect navLineFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 120.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 15.0f);
    self.navigationLineView = [[HyNavigationLineView alloc] initWithFrame:navLineFrame];

    // Make it's background transparent
    self.navigationLineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.0f];
    self.navigationLineView.opaque = NO;

    HyNavigationLineLayer * layer = [[HyNavigationLineLayer alloc] init];
    layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    layer.contentsScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;

    [[self.navigationLineView layer] addSublayer:layer];
    [self.view addSubview:self.navigationLineView];
    [self.navigationLineView.layer setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Here's how I'm drawing in the layer:

```
- (void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
    CGFloat bottomInset = 1.0f / [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] * 2.0f;

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(ctx, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);

    GLfloat padding = kHyNavigationLineViewPadding * 4.0f;
    GLfloat searchSpace = self.frame.size.width - padding - kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize * 2.0f;
    GLfloat x = kHyNavigationLineViewPadding * 2.0f + searchSpace * self.offset;

    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 2.0f);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, kHyNavigationLineViewPadding, 0.0f);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x, bottomInset);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x + kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize, self.frame.size.height);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x + kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize * 2.0f, bottomInset);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, self.frame.size.width - kHyNavigationLineViewPadding, 0.0f);

    // Draw
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

Any hints on how to solve this?

Edit: forgot to mention the reason I was drawing in the layer in the first place: I need to animate a property which causes this line to animate was well, so drawing in `drawRect` doesn't work.

Comment: Where/when do you tell the layer to draw itself? And when do you set the layer's frame? Specifically, I'm wondering if there's any way that the layer's contents are drawn while it's a smaller size, then subsequently scaled up during layout. One way to check would be to set `layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange = YES;` during your layer setup and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: Please see my edit. `layer.needsDisplayOnBoundsChange` doesn't seem to help...

Comment: Thanks. Shame! So what about you `HyNavigationLineLayer`'s frame? Where does that get set?

Comment: Pause in the debugger and run this command: `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.  Then, in the output, find the address of your `HyNavigationLineLayer`.  Run `po` on it.  (Example: if the output contains `<HyNavigationLineLayer: 0x79f5aee0>`, run `po 0x79f5aee0`.)  Copy all of the output of both commands and paste it into your question.

Comment: @stefandouganhyde, that's pretty much all the setup I have...

Comment: @robmayoff how do I do that?

Comment: Is it possible that your navLineFrame causes a disproportional scale on the y axis resulting in those artifacts? If that is the case, try adjusting the height of that frame.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it... At least drawing in the view draws properly, but I need to draw in the layer. But what kind of adjustment would you suggest? Reduce the frame's height?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using quartz to render the code, you can use UIBezierPath to render instead:

```
UIBezierPath* path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];

[[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];

GLfloat padding = kHyNavigationLineViewPadding * 4.0f;
GLfloat searchSpace = self.frame.size.width - padding - kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize * 2.0f;
GLfloat x = kHyNavigationLineViewPadding * 2.0f + searchSpace * self.offset;

path.lineWidth = 2.0;
[path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(kHyNavigationLineViewPadding, 0)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x, bottomInset)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize, self.frame.size.height)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(x + kHyNavigationLineViewPointerSize * 2.0f, bottomInset)];
[path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width - kHyNavigationLineViewPadding, 0.0f)];

[path stroke];
```

Comment: <Error>: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. This is a serious error. This application, or a library it uses, is using an invalid context  and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system stability and reliability. This notice is a courtesy: please fix this problem. It will become a fatal error in an upcoming update.

Comment: Should I not be drawing in `drawInContext:`?

Comment: You should be doing it in `-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` that is overridden from UIView

Comment: I'm sorry for my late reply, I've been busy. I can't draw in `drawRect:`, because I need to animate the property. That's the reason I used the layer in the first place.

Comment: try removing these lines                        `layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;`

Comment: I can't test it on the device right now, but it doesn't work on the simulator. I'll give you a confirmation for this later today!